# Why doesn't $z^n\cdot\left(\frac{a+b}{z}\right)^n = (a+b)^n$ always hold?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, maple

When I entered `is(z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n);` into Maple, the output was `false` and I guess Maple assumes that $a,b,n$ and $z$ can be any number in $ℂ$.

I thought
$$z^n\cdot\left(\frac{a+b}{z}\right)^n$$
was clearly
$$\left(z\cdot\frac{a+b}{z}\right)^n$$
and therefore
$$(a+b)^n$$

Why does this not apply?

**Edit:**
The output is still `false` when typing `assume(z <> 0): is(z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n);`

**Edit 2:**
`assume(z >= 0): is(z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n);` returns `true`.

**Edit 3:**
`assume(z = 0): is(z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n);` returns `false`.

*Isn't this a contradiction?*

**Edit 4:**
`assume(n in ℕ): is(z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n);` returns `false`.

For $a<0$ and $z<0$, Maple fails to evaluate the expression, although it is true. This means Maple returned `false` instead of admitting that it is unable to determine the result.
**This is a flaw.**

Comment: What about the $z=0$ case?

Comment: @Mattos I tried that. Maple throws a division-by-zero error.

Comment: @Mattos That cannot be since the expression $\;\frac{a+b}z\;$ is given, so it is assumed, I suppose, that automatically $\;z\neq0\;$

Comment: Have you typed it correctly? I really doubt. If yes then, yes! It's definitely a contradiction.

Comment: What if you enter that $n$ has to be a positive integer?

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: @Mankind Good point, I added that case to my answer. I think it suffices when $n$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In complex numbers, $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ does not necessarily hold.

$$((-1)(-1))^{1/2}=1\ne(-1)^{1/2}(-1)^{1/2}=i^2=-1.$$

Comment: I don't know, but since when does $(-1)^{1/2} = i$?

Comment: @user49685 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit

Comment: In complex numbers, $a^c$ is not even defined unambiguously.

Comment: Writing $(-1)^{1/2}=i$ is wrong to begin with, unless you specifically tell what branch of the square root you're using.

Comment: @user49685: since when does $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ hold ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Maple has trouble evaluating the left hand side of your equation. You can help Maple by asking it to `expand` (or `simplify`) the left-hand-side of your expression before using the `is` command from the assume facility.

```
eqn := z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n;
assume(z::real,n::integer);
```

As we saw in your question, `is(eqn);` returns `false` but

```
is(simplify(eqn));
```

returns `true`. I suppose this arises from limitations of the Assume Facility; [as referred to on the help page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=assume), this may be documented in [Corless, Monagan] (I was unable to find an online copy of it).

---

#### Side note

If $n$ is any complex number, we cannot say anything in general (non-uniqueness) but applying the assumption that $(a+b)/z>0$ seems to be enough for the Assume Facility (with a helping hand from the `simplify` command):

```
restart;
eqn := z^n*((a+b)/z)^n = (a+b)^n;

assume((a+b)/z>1);
is(simplify(eqn));
```

returns `true` although $z^n$ is ambiguous for $z,n \in \mathbb C$. This seems to be a result of the way Maple defines the complex exponential to have a unique solution, see [Section 5.1 The Complex Exponential Function](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4617) (document can only be opened in Maple).

<sub>[Corless, Monagan] Corless, Robert, and Monagan, Michael. "Simplification and the Assume Facility." Maple Technical Newsletter, Vol. 1 No. 1. Birkhauser, 1994.</sub>