# Plotting multiple functions in one plot - maple

Tags: normal-distribution, math-software, maple

Simple question which is bugging me quite a bit.

In maple I'm trying to graph 3 normal distributions, each one being a shift of the other.

I run the following code in maple and then get the following plot

```
plots[multiple](plot, [exp(-(x-4)^2), x = -5 .. 5], [exp(-(x-12)^2), x = -5 .. 5], [exp(-(x-20)^2), x = -100 .. 100]);
```

[image]

Which is an issue. I don't see what I did wrong. Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: what does this has to do with mathematics?

Comment: You did it right! What exactly are u looking for?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes.  To quote the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) immediately after "We welcome questions about:"

`Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site).`

Sounds like a Maple question is pretty on topic.  Why else do we even have a "maple" or "math-software" tag?

Comment: @tilper the tag is for questions about mathematics in Maple. I would say a good example is [Why doesn't $z^n*(\frac{a+b}{z})^n = (a+b)^n$ always hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685381/why-doesnt-zn-cdot-left-fracabz-rightn-abn-always-hold). For the programming part of Maple, the [Maple tag at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maple) is more appropriate.

Comment: @Therkel: Your proposed "good" Question is purely mathematical; it has nothing at all to do with Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the intervals:

```
[> with(plots):
   a := plot(exp(-(x-4)^2), x = -5 .. 15, color = blue):
   b := plot(exp(-(x-12)^2), x = -5 .. 15, color = red):
   c := plot(exp(-(x-20)^2), x = -10 .. 30, color = green):
   display(a, b, c);
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the help - I see I was overlapping.